# Regex expression for start with 2 * is not allowed

Tags: regex, typescript, regex-negation

I would like to know the regex for not allowing string like

```
**Test
```

but string like

```
*test, test,123,
```

is allowed. 
So basically start with 2 Asterix(*) is not allowed rest everything is allowed.

I have tried following regex expression

`[^(\*{2})].*
[^(\*\*)].*
[^(\*\*)$].*
^(?!\*\*.*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the start to avoid matching 2 stars.

```
/^(?!\*\*).*/

// or

/^(?!\*{2}).*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex 101](https://regex101.com) 
I managed to find any `*` following a `*` with this

```
(\*[^*]+.*)
```

and then I run an `or` on the other strings like this

```
^((\*[^*]+.*)|([^*]+.*))$
```